# Send file to (fetch to c# web api)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried to send file by JS Fetxh API to ASP .NET 6 WebAPI and get 400 status.

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('file', file)
const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7054/Pictures',
{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: data
});
```

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index([FromBody]IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Create))
        {
             await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

If delete FormData and send 'file' get the same error.
If delete 'Content-Type' get 415 status in every case.
If set 'Content-Type' to 'application/json' and IFormFile change to string, then send json it works ok.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: For example, if the problem is that your `catch` block is being triggered and you're getting back an HTTP 500 response, then take note of the fact that your `catch` block *ignores the actual exception*.  In such a case your first step would be to examine the exception being caught.

Comment: A multi-part form is MIME format and would look like following example.  The multi part is the body of the message and each part starts with a new line followed by two dashes.  You may be missing the dashes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`[FromBody]` is used receive `application/json` data. You need change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`

2.To upload files using `fetch` and `FormData`.you must not set `Content-Type` header.

Whole working demo below:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
const response = fetch('https://localhost:7054/Pictures',
{
    method: 'POST',  
    body: data
});
```

Api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
   //.....
}
```

Comment: The working demo link is missing.